# Laravel - Method [guest] does not exist on Redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Been searching hours for solution online but could not find a solution to this problem:

`BadMethodCallException in RedirectResponse.php line 228:
Method [guest] does not exist on Redirect.`

This is my controller:

```
class MemberController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('member.home');
    }
}

class SessionController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'destroy']);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('session.create');
    }
}
```

This is my routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/member', 'MemberController@index');
Route::get('/login', 'SessionController@create')->name('login');
```

When I try to access `127.0.0.1/member`, the above error pops up.

Any idea?

Comment: You don't seem to have a `create()` method in your `MembersController`?

Comment: what does you `auth` middleware look like

Comment: @RossWilson Somehow I copy and pasted wrong, fixed the typo.

Comment: @lagbox `php artisan make:auth`

Answer (score 1):

you are setting your `/member` route to point to `create` method, which is not exists in your member controller object,

this line:

```
Route::get('/member', 'MemberController@create');
```

you may need to change it to :

```
Route::get('/member', 'MemberController@index');
```

### OR

by changing your `index` method name in your member controller, or creating new method called `create` if you are using `index` method in another context:

```
public function index()
```

to be :

```
public function create()
```

Comment: Sorry, somehow I copy and pasted wrong, it was a typo

Comment: what's your base controller contents ?

Comment: Hi there, thank you for taking the time. My base controller is the default controller. I also posted my question right here where it contains further info: `https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/method-guest-does-not-exist-on-redirect `. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: did they there suggested a solution for this issue? or still opened?

Comment: and what happens when you comment this line `$this->middleware('auth');`

Comment: Hi @hassan, when I commented out `$this->middleware('auth');`, everything works fine, except that there no longer is a middleware. People at laracasts said that "From what I can understand, you're getting the wrong class, it should call `guest()` on `\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector` and not `\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse` when calling the `redirect()` helper.."

Comment: in your App\Http\Controllers, there are a basic controller called Controller.php , what's it's contents

Comment: That would be `use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;`